# How can I create a Vector of weekdays from "Today" to a date 75 days ago in R?

Tags: r, date

I want to create a vector that begins on the most recent weekday date and runs back for 75 days to the weekday 75 weekdays ago - how can I do this? Assume I can use seq? I'm very much a newbie to R.

If today is a Sunday (e.g. 21-08-2016), then the sequence should begin on the prior Friday (19-08-2016) and work back to the weekday 09-05-16. Very much similar to the Excel function =WORKDAY(A1,-1) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 75 days is not a large number, it might be something like this:

```
library(chron)
library(lubridate)
n = 75
Filter(function(x) !is.weekend(x), seq.Date(today(), by = '-1 day', length.out = (n+2)*7/5))[1:n]

 # [1] "2016-08-19" "2016-08-18" "2016-08-17" "2016-08-16"
 # [5] "2016-08-15" "2016-08-12" "2016-08-11" "2016-08-10"
 # ...
```

Comment: It seems like the down voter can provide a better answer. I am very curious and anxious to see it.

Comment: They didn't like my answer either

Comment: @RichardTelford He is trying to write a stream or generator for this problem, we will wait and see.

Comment: Neat solution but after installing the chron package and running the code I return:
Error in seq.Date(today(), by = "-1 day", length.out = (n + 2) * 7/5) : 
  could not find function "today"

Comment: Sorry. I forget to attach the `lubridate` package, where `today()` is from.

Answer (score 3):

We can make a sequence of days, reject any weekend days (NB - this will depend on your locale) and then trim the output to 75 days.

```
s1 <- seq(Sys.Date()-120, Sys.Date(), by = "day")
s1 <- s1[!weekdays(s1) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")] 
s1[(length(s1)-74):length(s1)]
```

To produce output in the other direction

```
n <- 75
s1 <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() - (n * 7/5 + 3) , by = "-1 day")
s1 <- s1[!weekdays(s1) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")] 
s1[1:n]
```

Comment: How to reverse this, so the most recent date is the first in the sequence? Tried wrapping the 2nd line in the rev() function but this resulted in a bad output.

Comment: see edited version.